# R: error in t test

Tags: r

https://filebin.net/3et86d1gh8cer9mu this is example subset of my data

I try to apply a code that was already working on similar data, now I can't tract where its wrong. The code goes like this:

```
url <- 'https://filebin.net/3et86d1gh8cer9mu/TCA_subset_GnoG_melt.csv'
TCA_subset_GnoG_melt  <- read.csv(url)
L <- data.frame()
IDs <- unique(TCA_subset_GnoG_melt$X1)
for (i in 1 : length(IDs)){

temp<-TCA_subset_GnoG_melt[(TCA_subset_GnoG_melt$X1)==IDs[i],]
temp<- na.omit(temp)
t_test_CTROL_ABC.7<- t.test(temp$value[temp$X1.1=="CTROL"],   temp$value[temp$X1.1=="ABC.7"])
t_test_CTROL_ABC.8<- t.test(temp$value[temp$X1.1=="CTROL"], temp$value[temp$X1.1=="ABC.8"])
t_test_CTROL_ABC.7.8<- t.test(temp$value[temp$X1.1=="CTROL"], temp$value[temp$X1.1=="ABC7.8"])

t_test_ABC.7_ABC.8<- t.test(temp$value[temp$X1.1=="ABC.7"], temp$value[temp$X1.1=="ABC.8"])
t_test_ABC.7_ABC.7.8<- t.test(temp$value[temp$X1.1=="ABC.7"], temp$value[temp$X1.1=="ABC7.8"])
t_test_ABC.8_ABC.7.8<- t.test(temp$value[temp$X1.1=="ABC.8"], temp$value[temp$X1.1=="ABC7.8"])

LLc <- cbind(as.character(unique(IDs[i])),   t_test_CTROL_ABC.7,t_test_CTROL_ABC.8,t_test_CTROL_ABC.7.8, t_test_ABC.7_ABC.8,t_test_ABC.7_ABC.7.8, t_test_ABC.8_ABC.7.8)
L<-rbind(L,LLc)
}

AA<-rownames(L)
L$names <- AA
p_value_TCA <-L[grep("p.value",L$names),  ]

df <- apply(p_value_TCA ,2,as.character)
df = as.matrix(df)
```

the error i get is:

```
Error in t.test.default(temp$value[temp$X1.1 == "CTROL"],    temp$value[temp$X1.1 ==  : 
  not enough 'y' observations
```

I dpm't understand it, when i check the code line by line it goes until the LLc creation and than the df "L" is empty. it makes no sense to me. help!

Comment: are you sure `X1` is the IDs and not `X2.1`? From where did you get the code?

Comment: maybe you got confused by `ABC.7.8` vs. `ABC7.8`?

Comment: yes, thanks I was stearing at it for too long andI confused the names with dots. That was a stupid question here, sorry to waste your time...